# Find algebraic equation for epicycloid $\theta \mapsto 4 e^{i\theta} - e^{4i\theta}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polar-coordinates, algebraic-curves, plane-curves

I am reading about [epicycloids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epicycloid) and I wonder if they are algebraic.  Here is in polar coordinates:

\begin{eqnarray*}
x(\theta) &=& (R+r) \cos \theta - r \cos \left( \frac{R+r}{r}  \theta\right) \\
y(\theta) &=& (R+r) \sin \theta - r \sin \left( \frac{R+r}{r}  \theta\right) \\
\end{eqnarray*}

Then is this curve algebraic?  If I add the real and imaginary parts we obtain:
$$ \theta \mapsto  (R+r) e^{i\theta} - r e^{i\frac{R+r}{r}  \theta} = 
(R+r) z - r z^{\frac{R+r}{r}  }  $$

Still is still not an equation of the type $f(x,y) = 0$.  The cardioid has an equation:

$$ (x^2 + y^2 +ax)^2 = a^2 (x^2 + y^2) $$

[image] [image] [image]